# How do I print the value of a hidden field in a text file?

Tags: c#, javascript, field, hidden

I have been trying to get the value that a user enters inside a text box to be stored in a hidden field since I needed to send it from client side to server side but I'm not even sure what is being stored in my hidden field. How can I send or copy that value into a text file?
So to break down my question:

- Take the value in the text box entered by the user and store it in hidden field.
- Print the value into a text file

Thank you in advance as I'm very new to C# and JavaScript

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET for this?

Comment: Nevermind, this is not a C# question

Comment: Check out [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) in javascript.

Comment: If the hidden field is a part of a form that gets submitted check the incoming POST or GET data

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is copy the value into a visible part of the page.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="testfield" />
```

Use the following JS:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.forms[0].testfield.value;
```

...then print the page.

Answer (score 1):

You would be far better off using a debugger and examining the passed value on the server side than writing to a text file on the server side.

Alternatively most browsers have a Developer mode that lets you look at the data that is being sent over the wire.  In IE for example, press F12, click Network and then Start Capturing.  That would allow you to see what data is being sent in all form fields, including the hidden one.

If you really want to write to a text file, you can use

```
File.WriteAllText(myPath, myText);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx